# New in R, problems in generating a correlation plot with corrplot of a large matrix

Tags: r, correlation, large-data, r-corrplot

I am new to R coding, and would like some help if possible. Can't seem to find an appropiate answer in the net.

I want to generate a color corrplot of a matrix with 91 variables. I would like to know:

- How to change labels font size so that it fits the plot.
- Is there any way to generate a larger plot so that I could effectively zoom in and see every square detailed?

This is the code used. Just loading the library and applying the plot:

`library(corrplot) M <- cor(file_name) corrplot(M, method = "color")`

[image: Link to image]

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, use a device like `help("pdf")` and specify suitable dimensions. Personally, I'd say this is a useless plot but suit yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You find help for various options like the font size in the [docs for corrplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/corrplot.pdf) (e.g. `tl.cex=)`. Your question would also benefit if you would provide a [mcve], because it is easier for people who want to help. Please consider to read our [How to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).